# River catchment dataset for the Middle East

Tags: data-request, geospatial, hydrology

I need river catchment spatial data belonging to the Middle East for a research project. It can be any spatial data format(GeoPackage, GeoJSON, Shapefile, CSV with coordinate, KML, etc.). I can easily convert it to the format I need.

All I found in the context of hydrology is [Geo-referenced database of dams (Middle East)](https://data.apps.fao.org/catalog/iso/2109a932-162c-43fc-bbe5-cb454ab2905a). There are other kind of hydrological data like rivers, lakes etc, but no river catchments.

Comment: Actually, I would have asked in GIS StackExchange, but the folks in GISSE are directing me here for the open data requests.

Comment: Why not calculate it by yourself? Example here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303786/define-catchment-boundaries-with-gis-using-r. How/Where to find/get the elevation data (not only for R): http://www.sapijaszko.net/glupotki/posts/dem_altitude/

Answer (score 1):

A source of freely available global catchments and networks are accessible from [HYDROSHEDS](https://www.hydrosheds.org/).